# Why does it go through netfilter postrouting when visiting local ports?

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-kernel, netfilter

Environment：

```
[root@VM-32-4-centos ~]# uname -r
3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
```

I have set log printing in the following chain：

```
[root@VM-32-4-centos ~]# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT DPORT 8000 LOGS: "
[root@VM-32-4-centos ~]# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT SPORT 8000 LOGS: "
[root@VM-32-4-centos ~]# iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT DPORT 8000 LOGS: "
[root@VM-32-4-centos ~]# iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT SPORT 8000 LOGS: "
[root@VM-32-4-centos ~]# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --sport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "POSTROUTING SPORT 8000 LOGS: "
[root@VM-32-4-centos ~]# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 8000 -j LOG --log-prefix "POSTROUTING DPORT 8000 LOGS: "
```

Then I execute the telnet command：

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8000
```

tail -f /var/log/message, show the following：

```
May  2 23:54:47 VM-32-4-centos kernel: OUTPUT DPORT 8000 LOGS: IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=6163 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51096 DPT=8000 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May  2 23:54:47 VM-32-4-centos kernel: POSTROUTING DPORT 8000 LOGS: IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=6163 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51096 DPT=8000 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May  2 23:54:47 VM-32-4-centos kernel: INPUT DPORT 8000 LOGS: IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=6163 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51096 DPT=8000 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
May  2 23:54:47 VM-32-4-centos kernel: OUTPUT SPORT 8000 LOGS: IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=8000 DPT=51096 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
May  2 23:54:47 VM-32-4-centos kernel: INPUT SPORT 8000 LOGS: IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=8000 DPT=51096 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0 
May  2 23:54:47 VM-32-4-centos kernel: OUTPUT DPORT 8000 LOGS: IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=52 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=6164 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51096 DPT=8000 WINDOW=342 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
May  2 23:54:47 VM-32-4-centos kernel: INPUT DPORT 8000 LOGS: IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=52 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=6164 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51096 DPT=8000 WINDOW=342 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

Excuse me, when accessing locally, why does SYN packet go through POSTROUTING?

Subsequent ACK+SYN packets did not go through POSTROUTING, why?

May I ask why this is so, is there any information about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this is a local port changes nothing in the fact that you
have an outgoing connection and an ingoing connection.

The NAT tables are used on the first packet of a connection for
finding which translations should be applied to that connection.

During the first packet processing, an internal mapping table entry
is created which is used to process later packets of the connection.
This is why you see more work done for the first packet than for
the following ones.